# How to reference an USB port via avrdude?

Tags: avr, avrdude

avrdude has the option `p` which permits you to determine which port should be used.

By checking the USB settings of my USBASP, it says it is connected through the port#0002.hub#0001. So I tried the following:

```
avrdude -p m168p -c avrisp -P com2 -b 19200
```

Unfortunately it didn't work:

```
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.
```

USBASP has been updated to the latest version and the -F option doesn't work either.

Am I referencing the USB port correctly by calling is COM2?
Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

USB port number have nothing to do with the COM port number. (COM are virtual nowadays)
Basically you want to know which COM port windows uses for your USB device.

Go to your device manager to see what COM port your avr writing device is using:
[com port info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIkKf.png)

You can even change it via your USB device's properties if you want.
(Properties -> Port settings -> Port COM number)